# Set Logitech Steering Wheel position/angle from SDL?

Tags: sdl, sdl-2, haptic-feedback

I'm writing C code that controls a Logitech gaming wheel using SDL. So far I have successfully implemented the code that sets the steering wheel in autocenter mode with:

```
SDL_HapticSetAutocenter(haptic, STRENGTH); //set autocenter
```

I would like to be able to use the motor of the steering wheel to rotate it as desired to particular angle positions. After checking in the [documentation of the API](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryForceFeedback), I did not find a simple way to do it.

I wonder if anyone has some advice on this.

Comment: Experiment with a `SDL_HAPTIC_CONSTANT` effect & [`SDL_HAPTIC_POLAR`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_HapticDirection#type) with the desired angle?  I *think* that ought to drive the wheel to the given angle.